# @ApiModelProperty: set the property 'required = true' conditionally

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, swagger

I am trying to implement two endpoints in a spring boot application:

POST: api/v1/student

PUT: api/v1/student/{student_id}

The request payload these API takes are same i.e. StudentCreation.java

```
@Data
public class StudentCreation {

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    private String firstName;

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    private String lastName;

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    private String address;

}
```

For POST endpoint all the fields are required in the payload, but for PUT one the firstName, lastName is optional.

The worst case I need to have two different classes for POST and PUT payload requests.
So, is there any way we can achieve this with a single class i.e. keep the required=true for POST only and required=false for PUT request?

Or any other better approach is also appreciated.

Comment: You'll need 2 separate schemas/classes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set required on **@ApiModelProperty** with optional condition. You can either have two seperate model or you can use **@ApiParam** on the parameters so that you can specify whether the parameter is required or optional.

You can check the usage of @ApiParam here : [https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-apiparam-vs-apimodelproperty#:~:text=The%20%40ApiModelProperty%20annotation%20allows%20us,the%20property%20in%20certain%20scenarios](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-apiparam-vs-apimodelproperty#:%7E:text=The%20%40ApiModelProperty%20annotation%20allows%20us,the%20property%20in%20certain%20scenarios).